# Showing $ \left \lceil \frac{a}{b} \right \rceil \leq \frac{a+b-1}{b}$

Tags: alternative-proof, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm trying to convince myself how one can hypothesize that

$$ \left \lceil \frac{a}{b} \right \rceil \leq \frac{a+b-1}{b}$$
or alternatively that
$$ \left \lceil \frac{a}{b} \right \rceil -\frac{a}{b}\leq 1-\frac{1}{b}. $$

My best answer is to roll into the proof, but I would not try to prove it because I'm not sure I would hypothesize the claim. (I probably will see that it is not tight, and then try to generate a better claim). Last but not least, it seems to me that equality occurs whenever $a+b+1$ is a multiply of $b$. Can you articulate what this condition means?

**Proof.**
The proof splits into two cases:

- $\left \lceil \frac{a}{b} \right \rceil =\frac{a}{b}$, then trivially the difference is zero and the claim follows.
- $\left \lceil \frac{a}{b} \right \rceil >\frac{a}{b}$. Then, $\frac{a}{b} > \left \lceil \frac{a}{b} \right \rceil - 1$ multplying by $b$ yields:
  $ a>\left \lceil \frac{a}{b} \right \rceil b-b$, substract $a$ to obtain $\left \lceil \frac{a}{b} \right \rceil b-b-a < 0$, and using the fact that the rhs must be an integer to deduce
  $\left \lceil \frac{a}{b} \right \rceil b-b-a \leq 1$. Finally devide everything by $b$ and get
  $$\left \lceil \frac{a}{b} \right \rceil-\frac{a}{b} \leq 1 - \frac{1}{b}.$$
  Q.E.D.

Comment: Hint: \lfloor \frac ab \rfloor = n = \frac{nb}b$ for some special integer $n$. What would happen if the inequality were violated?

Comment: @Martin R. Kinda, if we write $a=qb+r$ then $\left \lceil \frac{a}{b} \right \rceil -\frac{a}{b}=\left \lceil \frac{qb+r}{b} \right \rceil-\frac{qb+r}{b}=q+1-q-r/b=1-r/b$, as long as $0 < r \leq b-1$. But, still I don't know why $r\leq 1$?

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ supposed to be integers?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your proof, assuming $a$ and $b$ are positive integers. (I think it even works for negative integers but I didn't scrutinize edge cases.